# Creating Dynamic References in java

Tags: java, reference

I have two classes.

```
package utilities;

public class PostCaller {

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
    public String getRequest() {
        return request;
    }
    public void setRequest(String request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    String request  = null;
    String url      = null;

}

public class TestLoader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Object obj = Class.forName("utilities.PostCaller").newInstance();
        System.out.println(obj.getClass().getName()); // This prints utilities.PostCaller
    }
}
```

I want to create a new Instatnce of the PostCaller and call it's method from the TestLoader class. Here, I have a question of creating a reference of that utilities.PostCaller class.
That means, I want to create a reference variable whose name is dyanamically given by a String (eg : utilities.PostCaller). 
Here although I have created a new Instance of the utilities.PostCaller, I cannot call it's methods since I don't have created a reference of it.

Comment: What is the question? What do you expect this code to do? How is that different from what it does do?

Comment: If you are trying to ask more about reflections api then here is the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)

Comment: I mentioned it in the question. It may not be cleared. I edditted it now. What I want is creating a reference variable whose name is dyanamically given by the name. (eg : utilities.PostCaller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood you just wanna test your PostCaller...I
If true, [EasyMock](http://www.easymock.org/) library can help ypu in this case. You can search via google a lot of examples, here is one http://tersesystems.com/2007/06/25/easymock-examples.

Comment: This post caller is just a sample class. What I actually want is creating instants and call their methods dynamically. That's I asked for a way to create dynamic references.